# Get authority from username in header for spring security

Tags: java, spring-security, siteminder

I need to implement spring security for my api-controller.

-> Each page should contain a header with username (like in Siteminder?).
-> Every user has been already registered in SpringConfiguration

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                ... gets all users from database with their authorities
}
```

-> For every page it's configured, which authorities a user should have

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("**/Pagename/**").hasAuthority("authorityName");
    }
```

I cannot understand now, what should I add to make the program read a username from page header. RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter? Another kind of filter?

The other question is if you could give me a link to tutorial/examle how to build it in without using XML.

Comment: I found a good configuration example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844236/spring-security-java-config-for-siteminder

Answer (score 0):

try to put the following JSTL where you need to get the username 
"${pageContext.request.remoteUser}"

Comment: I don't need to display it. I need to extract it from header and check authorities of this user.

Comment: then use custom security filter just search how to use custom security filter in spring 4

Answer (score -1):

take a look at This Guide :
[Hello Spring Security Java Config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x-SNAPSHOT/guides/helloworld.html)

Comment: How does it help me? There are no examples with username in the page-header and filters. The other stuff, as you see above, I have already implemented by myself.

Comment: if you need userName
((HttpServletRequest)request).getUserPrincipal().getName()

if you need authorities
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()

a link to the first method is in that guide

Comment: I need to extract username from page-header

Comment: Then you can get it from HttpServletrequest ((HttpServletRequest)request).getUserPrincipal().getName()